# Laravel upsert createing duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$responsible_users = collect($request->responsible_users)->map(fn ($user_id) => new OrganizationElementUser(['user_id' => $user_id, 'organization_element_id' => $organization_element_id, 'type' => DeviceAuthAndHierarchyElementRole::RESPONSIBLE_ROLE]));
$subordinate_users = collect($request->subordinate_users)->map(fn ($user_id) => new OrganizationElementUser(['user_id' => $user_id, 'organization_element_id' => $organization_element_id, 'type' => DeviceAuthAndHierarchyElementRole::DIRECT_SUBORDINATE_ROLE]));

$internal_users = $responsible_users->merge($subordinate_users)->toArray();
OrganizationElementUser::upsert($internal_users, ['user_id', 'organization_element_id', 'type'], ['user_id', 'organization_element_id', 'type']);
```

Why is my upsert creating duplicate records?

My `user_id`, `organization_element_id`, `type` fields can individually be duplicate but all 3 of them combined creates a unique record

ex. of what I want is:

```
user_id == 1 && organization_element_id == 2 && type == 'test'
//ignore if true otherwise insert
```

Comment: Laravel documentation : "All databases except SQL Server require the columns in the second argument of the upsert method to have a "primary" or "unique" index. In addition, the MySQL database driver ignores the second argument of the upsert method and always uses the "primary" and "unique" indexes of the table to detect existing records."

Comment: @StewieSWS Does the only way I have is to check every single insertion manually or is there any other tricks available? I am using MySQL BTW.

Comment: You can use foreach and updateOrCreate() method, but it could be very slow. Or you might  update your migration with rule `$table->unique(['user_id', 'organization_element_id', 'type']);` and see if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UpdateOrCreate` method. Documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#upserts).

```
                User::updateOrCreate([
                    'user_id' => $user_id, 
                    'organization_element_id' => 2,
                    'type' => 'test'], //if everything matches with these conditions, the row will get updated, otherwise, it will be inserted. It is like the where clause.
                    ['column_xyz' => $request->new_string],
                );
```

Answer (score -1):

Had similar problem, found the answer in @StewieSWS comment of the question:

```
Laravel documentation:

"All databases except SQL Server require the columns in the second argument of the upsert method to have a "primary" or "unique" index. In addition, the MySQL database driver ignores the second argument of the upsert method and always uses the "primary" and "unique" indexes of the table to detect existing records."
```

so basically the parameter that specify unique columns is ignored, you have to set UNIQUE key in mysql/mariadb tables